# How to start specific activity by saying OK Google?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-voice, google-voice-actions

I would like to have two activities. `FirstActivity` should be started from
launcher (by tapping on icon) and `SecondActivity` should be started by voice
command (by saying "OK Google, start play example").

The problem is that for my current configuration only `FirstActivity` is
started. Also method `isVoiceInteraction` returns `false`. I also don't see any values in `flags` that indicates that activity was started by voice.

Here's part of `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:label="play example">
    <activity android:name="com.example.FirstActivity" android:label="play example">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.EXAMPLE_ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.SecondActivity" android:label="play example">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.EXAMPLE_ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html) it states:

> To specify the text to say after "Start", specify a label attribute for the activtiy that you want to start.

But when I change `label` for `SecondActivity` it does not help.

I'm using API version 26.

How to setup configuration to handle described behavior?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `isVoiceInteraction` will always return `false` when the application is opened using "open" voice command. However, the scenario which you described, having another activity to respond to voice commands, should've worked.

The only thing that you might have missed is to put the action `android.intent.action.MAIN` in the second activity.